# What is the right format of PATH variable

Tags: environment-variables, path, macos

I have a macOS and this is the output I get when I do `echo $PATH`

```
usr/local/opt/avr-gcc@8/bin:/Users/hari/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/flutter/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/.npm/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/flutter/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/.pub-cache/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/flutter/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/.npm/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/flutter/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/.:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/flutter/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/.npm/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/flutter/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/.pub-cache/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/flutter/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/.npm/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/flutter/bin:/Users/hari/.edgedb/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/hari/.cargo/bin:/Users/hari/.fig/bin:/usr/local/go:/Users/hari/go:/Users/hari/go/bin:/Users/hari/.fzf/bin
```

Is this right? Is this long and if long how can i make it short. plz help

Comment: Did you source your shells startup-scripts manually several times, or is that the value of `$PATH` in a freshly opened terminal? Most paths are repeated 16 times. The first path lacks `/` at the start.  There are a few paths that repeat 8, 4 and 2 times too.  Usually, each path in the value is never repeated at all, which indicates that you have added a number of paths far to many times, possibly by re-sourcing the shell's startup-scripts. What shell are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, it is value on of ````$PATH```` in a freshly opened terminal. I am using iterm and zsh.. I also have Fig installed and most of the time I install something which requires me to add to ````$PATH```` I keep adding them along with PATH appended. like ````export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH````
Thanks for pointing out the repeating stuff. I will make sure only one path is there and also add the ````/````.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
$ printf '%s\n' $path | sort | uniq -c
  16 /Library/Apple/usr/bin
  16 /Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin
  16 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin
  16 /Users/hari/.cargo/bin
  16 /Users/hari/.edgedb/bin
  16 /Users/hari/.fig/bin
   1 /Users/hari/.fzf/bin
   4 /Users/hari/.npm/bin
   2 /Users/hari/.pub-cache/bin
   1 /Users/hari/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/.
   8 /Users/hari/flutter/bin
  16 /Users/hari/go
  16 /Users/hari/go/bin
   1 /Users/hari/google-cloud-sdk/bin
  16 /bin
  16 /opt/X11/bin
  16 /sbin
  16 /usr/bin
  16 /usr/local/bin
  16 /usr/local/go
  16 /usr/local/go/bin
  16 /usr/sbin
   1 usr/local/opt/avr-gcc@8/bin
```

As you can see, your `PATH` variable contains multiple copies of paths, making it excessively long.

This could be handled in a way that is specific (and possibly unique) to the `zsh` shell.  In that shell, the scalar `$PATH` variable is "tied" to the array variable `$path` (used in the short piece of shell code above), which means that changing one will update the other automatically.  Furthermore, in the `zsh` shell, an array variable may be declared to "only contain unique elements".  Applying this to the `PATH` and `path` variables, we get a way of making sure that the `PATH` does not grow like what yours have done.

```bsh
typeset -g -U PATH path
```

The `-g` option to `typeset` makes it declare the given variables as "global" (rather than "local" to the current scope), and `-U` makes the `path` variable keep only the first occurrence of each variable.

Adding that `typeset` command to the first one of `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc` that exists in your home directory would make sure that it is active for your interactive shell sessions in the terminal.

```bsh
$ typeset -g -U PATH path
$ printf '%s\n' $path  | sort | uniq -c
   1 /Library/Apple/usr/bin
   1 /Library/Frameworks/EdgeDB.framework/bin
   1 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin
   1 /Users/hari/.cargo/bin
   1 /Users/hari/.edgedb/bin
   1 /Users/hari/.fig/bin
   1 /Users/hari/.fzf/bin
   1 /Users/hari/.npm/bin
   1 /Users/hari/.pub-cache/bin
   1 /Users/hari/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/.
   1 /Users/hari/flutter/bin
   1 /Users/hari/go
   1 /Users/hari/go/bin
   1 /Users/hari/google-cloud-sdk/bin
   1 /bin
   1 /opt/X11/bin
   1 /sbin
   1 /usr/bin
   1 /usr/local/bin
   1 /usr/local/go
   1 /usr/local/go/bin
   1 /usr/sbin
   1 usr/local/opt/avr-gcc@8/bin
```

To add a path to the end of `PATH`,

```bsh
path+=( '/new/path' )
```

or

```bsh
path=( $path '/new/path' )
```

To add a path to the start of `PATH`,

```bsh
path=( '/new/path' $path )
```

If the `path` variable has been made "unique" with `typeset -U`, only the first occurrence of the new path will be kept in the variable.

Comment: Thanks so much.. I got the things working here. However, after I close the terminal and open it again it goes back to the previous long path with duplicates. How can I persist the new path across terminals and new sessions

Comment: @p2hari Sorry, I should have said, add that `typeset` command to the first one of `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc` that you have in your home directory.  I will update the answer with this missing information.

Answer (score 3):

`PATH` is a colon-separated list of directories your shell searches for executables. `PATH` manipulation is difficult, but there are tools. I use Stephen Collyer's bash_path_funcs, described in Linux Journal way back in 2000:

https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3645
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3768
https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3935

The `addpath` function adds an entry to a path only if it is not there in the first place. `delpath -n` deletes all non-existent directories from a path. `uniqpath` eliminates duplicates.

You can get the `pathfunc.tgz` file from  https://web.archive.org/web/20061210054813/http://www.netspinner.co.uk:80/Downloads/pathfunc.tgz

Comment: It's a little older than that (but original author likely unknown - see [this](https://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:newpath), and [this](https://invisible-island.net/conflict/conflict.html#path-updates)).

Comment: wow, this is cool. I just downloaded them and unzipped and trying to run them but was not successful. Sorry, I am kind of new to all this. But I did go through the readme and the blogs. but could not follow. I opened the folder and went inside the bash functions. and try to run it and end up with ````./uniqpath: command not found````

Comment: See also: [Add directory to $PATH if it's not already there](https://superuser.com/q/39751/150988).